# Update document inside array of objects in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I need to update objects inside an array so I'm trying but I get the following error:

> error Plan executor error during findAndModify ::  caused by :: The
> positional operator did not find  the match needed from the query.

This is my code:

```
        const payment = await Purchase.findByIdAndUpdate( 
        { '_id': req.body.id, 'payments._id': req.body.paymentId },
        {
          $set: {
            'payments.$.status': false
          }
        }
        ,{ new: true });
```

payments object on Model:

```
 payments: [
    {
      createdBy: [Object],
      createdAt: '08/13/22',
      paymentNumber: 0,
      previousBalance: 3747.68,
      paymentAmount: 3747.68,
      outstandingBalance: 0,
      status: true,
      _id: new ObjectId("62f83f3c22e4f67dde8cb85a"),
      lastModificationBy: [],
      disabledBy: []
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

while using fineByIdAndUpdate you only need to pass id of document to be updated.

```
const payment = await Purchase.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.paymentId,{status:false},{new:true} )
```

Answer (score 0):

for using `findByIdAndUpdate`, you need to add this `runValidators`

```js
const payment = await Purchase.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, 
  'payments.$.status': false
}, {runValidators: true}
```

while same update can be done by this as well

```js
const payment = await Purchase.findByIdAndUpdate(
  req.body.paymentId,
  {
    status:false
  }, {
    new:true
  }
)
```